# How do I hide dynamic elements in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, dom, meteor, spacebars

So I have a bunch of templates that will be iterated with `{{#each game}}` showing the following template:

```
<template name="game">
{{#if condition}}
    <div class="box">
        Page 1
    </div>
{{else}}
    <div class="box">
        Page 2
    </div>
{{/if}}
</template>
```

I want to display "Page 2" when the "Page 1" box is clicked, so I have the following:

```
Template.game.events({
    'click .box': function(e) {
        Session.set("condition", true);
    }
});
```

But I do not want all of the other game templates to transition to Page 2, just the one that was clicked. How do I accomplish this?

EDIT: The change should only affect the current user, not all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your games are stored in a `Meteor.Collection`, and `condition` is a property on the documents that should reflect for all users, not just the current one, you can do something like this:

```
Template.game.events({
    'click .box': function(event, template) {
        Games.update(
            {_id: template.data._id},
            {$set: {condition: !template.data.condition}}
        );
    }
});
```

If it should only affect the current user, you can use a template-instance specific session variable and return it with a helper function called `condition`:

```
Template.game.events({
    'click .box': function(event, template) {
        Session.set("condition-" + template.data._id, true);
    }
});

Template.game.condition = function() {
    return Session.get("condition-" + this._id);
};
```

You could achieve similar functionality with a local collection.

Comment: Ah, I should have specified that it should effect only the current user.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Session variables! The very reason is the problem you have, they're equivalent of the old global variables. Use template's data instead, it's local and can be used to control the behavior like you want in this case.

For the template in your example:

```
Template.game.created = function() {
  this.data.conditionValue = 'something';
  this.data.conditionDep = new Deps.Dependency();
};

Template.game.condition = function() {
  this.conditionDep.depend();
  return this.conditionValue;
};

Template.game.events({
  'click .box': function(e, t) {
    t.data.conditionValue = 'somethingElse';
    t.data.conditionDep.changed(); 
  },
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I've never tried this because of this warning in the docs about the data property of template instances: "Access is read-only and non-reactive." as well as "You cannot currently access the template instance object from helpers. We plan to refactor how template instances work and make them more universally accessible." If this works then it definitely seems cleaner than using session vars with `_id`s in the key.

Comment: The second part is correct, you don't access the template from helper, just its data which is provided as a context. The access is non-reactive indeed, that's why you need to provide your own dependency. I didn't notice the warning about the data being read-only, nor did I have any problems with that – I use this pattern all the time. Is it possible to check since when that warning is there? Perhaps it's something new, but I didn't notice any problems in the current release.

Comment: After some testing, it appears that any custom fields added to the template instance's `data` object are removed when changes are made to the document from the `meteor mongo` console. I assume this probably also applies to changes made by other meteor users or the server. Unfortunately, it seems the best way right now to do something like this is with `Session`, a local collection, or a custom reactive data source that is not located on the template instance. If/when helpers can access the template instance itself, it would probably be safe to add fields directly to it, rather than `data`.

Comment: As a sidenote, template instances are not preserved on refreshes or hot code pushes, so it may not be such a great storage space for info like this. Seems like a local collection would be the best all-around solution.

Comment: Thanks for the find! Seems like I need to adjust my views.

Answer (score 0):

I also feel using a session with id doesn't sound like the best idea, and found this answer which seems to be better than using session: [Using Meteor sessions to toggle templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909787/using-meteor-sessions-to-toggle-templates)